# SQL: a way to compare rows from result set without self-join

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

Is there a way to compare 2 rows of a table without self-join?

I have a table of events with columns: ID, date, tool. I query it, and add row numbers to the result set (sorted by date, for each tool separately). Now I want to know if the time difference between rows 1 and 4 is more than a week.
I could achieve this by joining my query to itself (pretty simple), however it will make the query run twice (right?) which is not very efficient (as my query is not simple and already required some joining). Is there a smarter way to achieve this?

I am using SQL server (not sure which version; probably 2008), and querying from an ASP.NET application, so I don't have administrative access to the DB, and some advanced stuff will not work (but I'm willing to try every suggestion and check).
Thanks.

Comment: You can use a temp table to store the result set and then do the operations you need.

Comment: @dcp1986: How do I do this?

Comment: It depends on which version of SQL Server you are using. For example: If you are on >=2005 SQL Server then Windowing Functions will allow you to do what you want without self joining. So, post which version of SQL Server you are on.

Comment: @SashikanthDareddy: I'm not sure, probably 2008, definitely >=2005. What windowing function can I use? I don't know of any appropriate one.

Comment: @My apologies, it appears the part of Windowing Function which I thought might help is only available in SQL Server 2012. see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.110).aspx. It is the ability to define ranges over arbitary no. of rows is what is missing in <2012 versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with windowing functions to achieve your goal, but maybe over(partition by ... order by) will suffice (`http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2d448/1`):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SomeTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #SomeTable
END

create table #SomeTable (Id int, [date] datetime, tool nvarchar(80), description nvarchar(80))

DECLARE @date AS DATETIME

SET @date = CAST('2013-01-10' as datetime) 

declare @i as int = 0
declare @j as int = 0
declare @k as int = 0

WHILE (@i < 100)
begin
    set @i = @i + 1
    set @j = 0
    WHILE (@j < 100)
    begin
        set @j = @j + 1
        set @k = CAST(RAND() * 100 as int)      
        insert into #SomeTable (Id, [date], tool, description) values (@i*@j, DATEADD(dd,@k,@date), 'tool-' + STUFF('000', 3-LEN(@i)+1, LEN(@i), @i) , 'description-' + CAST(@i as nvarchar(10)) + '-' + CAST(@j as nvarchar(10)))
    end
end
--may be this will be enough
--select *, DATEDIFF(dd, MIN([date]) OVER(PARTITION BY tool), [date]) AS 'days' from #SomeTable order by tool, days
--sql 2012 only
--4 rows window
--select *, DATEDIFF(dd, MIN([date]) OVER(PARTITION BY tool ORDER BY tool, [date] ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), [date]) AS 'days' from #SomeTable order by tool, days
select *, DATEDIFF(dd, MIN([date]) OVER(ORDER BY tool, [date] ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), [date]) AS 'days' from #SomeTable order by tool, days
```